# mysql - "trending" function a la reddit/hackernews performance issues

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

I have a table of posts that I'd like to order using a function similar to that of hacker news or reddit - values "likes - dislikes" and recency. The problem: it is very slow (even though all the relevant fields are indexed). How can I speed it up?

Query (pseudo):

```
SELECT * FROM Post WHERE foo = 'bar' ORDER BY 
((p.like_count - p.dislike_count) / POW(((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - p.time / 3600) + 2, 1.5))
```

My first instinct is to try calculating UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) outside of the query, though I don't know what the performance of POW() looks like either.

Comment: Would you be able to post the `EXPLAIN` output for your query? I.e. run `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM ..... etc`

Comment: You could replace `POW(x, 1.5)` by `SQRT(x * x * x)` but I doubt it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was to discard entirely posts older than a couple of weeks. Since trending is only interested in recent content, it doesn't need to pull from the archives of history.

```
$oldestAllowed = time() - 3600*24*14; // 14 days
SELECT * FROM Post WHERE p.time > $oldestAllowed ORDER BY
((p.like_count - p.dislike_count) / POW(((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - p.time / 3600) + 2, 1.5))
```